# Бот не видит команды в чате дискорда

Tags: javascript, бот

Добрый день создал бота для чата дискорда, загрузил его на сервер.
По задумке бот должен после команды !ft (скорость+расстояние) выдавать сообщение о затраченном времени.
Но когда я пишу в любом канале эту команду то ничего не происходит. Куда рыть?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js'); 
const bot = new Discord.Client();
//подключаем файл конфигурации
let config = require('./botconfig.json'); 
//"достаём" токен и префикс
let token = config.token; 
let prefix = config.prefix;
//создаём ссылку-приглашение для бота
bot.on('ready', () => { 
  console.log(`Запустился бот ${bot.user.username}`);
  bot.generateInvite(["ADMINISTRATOR"]).then(link => { 
  console.log(link);
});
});
//команда, и то, что она должна выполнить
bot.on('message', msg => {
  if(message.content.startsWith("!ft")){
    let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1)
    let x = args[0].split("+")[0]
    let y = args[0].split("+")[1]
    
    let time = require('ms-advanced')(Math.floor(x/y)*60000)
    message.channel.send(`Время полёта составит ${time.replace("h","ч").replace(/[0-9]+ms/g,"").replace("s","сек").replace("m","мин")}
    ${Math.floor(y/200)} SU, где: 1 SU = 200 км
    `)
    }
});
bot.login(token);
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYDm3.png]

Answer (score 1):

Одна из ошибок указывается в консоли

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы в функции передаёте параметр как переменную `msg`, а обращаетесь к `message`

```
//                   ⇩
bot.on('message', message => {
  if(message.content.startsWith("!ft")){
    let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1)
    let x = args[0].split("+")[0]
    let y = args[0].split("+")[1]
    
    let time = require('ms-advanced')(Math.floor(x/y)*60000)
    message.channel.send(`Время полёта составит ${time.replace("h","ч").replace(/[0-9]+ms/g,"").replace("s","сек").replace("m","мин")}
    ${Math.floor(y/200)} SU, где: 1 SU = 200 км
    `)
  }
});
```